# Merge on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, upsert, sql-merge

Is it possible to use multiple conditions on SQL merge ON condition to make as unique identifier instead of concatenating?

CompanyId+StoreLocation = UniqueId. I do not want to create an additional concatenated column. Will this work? If not, what could be the best solution?

**`ON (target.CompanyId = source.CompanyId AND target.Storelocation = source.storelocation)`**

```
CompanyId   StoreLocation   StoreSQM
------------------------------------
12345       Chicago01        1650
12345       Chicago02        1985
12652       Milwaukee        1865
45846       Minneapolis     45845
```

```
MERGE dbo.storestbl AS target
USING stagingtbl AS source 
      **ON (target.CompanyId = source.CompanyId AND target.Storelocation = source.storelocation)**

WHEN MATCHED THEN
   Do something

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   Do something
```

Comment: yes. But your parenthesis is wrong. Should be simply `ON target.CompanyId = source.CompanyId AND target.Storelocation = source.storelocation`

Comment: @Squirrel Nothing wrong or illegal about the parentheses. The documentation has multiple examples of that usage.

Comment: my bad. Thought I saw it was on the wrong place.

Comment: @Squirrel,
So adding AND will act as a concatenation and convert it as unique ID right?

Comment: `AND` means both conditions must be true.